# Time Series Regression in R: Help from the ground up

Tags: r, time, time-series, regression, linear-regression

I am very inexperienced in R but I am told it is the premier statistical package. I have studied it in the interest of doing research but I am at an impasse with respect to time series data, specifically regression. I know how to do multiple regression and I somewhat know how to do forecasting with SARIMA models, but I am unsure how to do a time series multiple regression.

Here is a sample of my data first. I always import from a CSV.

```
     HomRate   Unemp    Av_Schl     GNI_perCapita   
2000    5.5    4.099    12.7        36930   
2001    6.6    4.800    N/A         37860   
2002    5.6    5.900    N/A         38590   
2003    5.6    6.099    N/A         39960   
2004    5.5    5.599    12.87391    42260   
2005    5.6    5.199    12.8        44740   
2006    5.8    4.699    12.96034    47390
2007    5.6    4.699    N/A         48420
2008    5.4    5.900    13.20913    48640
2009    5.0    9.399    13.29049    47250
```

Homicide, or HomRate, is the dependent variable, and the others are independent. For the sake of this, let's say there are no transformations on the data.

From my limited understanding, instead of using an `lm`, like in multiple linear regression, I use a `tslm`, from the `forecast` package. However, my data doesn't read as a time series data, according to R; how can I make that happen? No example I've found actually shows me the underlying data, so I don't know what proper ts compatible data looks like.

If I get the `tslm` command off the ground, would the rest of the logic be like multiple regression? (ie `model=tslm(HomRate~Unemp+Av_Schl+...)`) Or is it very different in terms of coding?

Thank you very much, and please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: You could take a look at the open source text [Forecasting: principles and practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp) by Rob Hyndman, who is also the author of the `forecast` package. Although not open source, there's also [Introductory Time Series with R](https://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Time-R-Use/dp/0387886974/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1491789821&sr=8-1&keywords=cowpertwait+time+series).

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! I found 4.8 helpful, but when I went to download the data he used from his package `fpp`, called US consumption, I was unable to discern what made his ts data different from my data. Whenever I use the dataset above, I get `Not time series data, use lm()`, and I don't see what's different about Hyndman's data to not incur that error.

Comment: Your data may be "time series" data, but the functions you're trying to use probably also need you to convert your data frame to a time series *class*. For example, if you run `class(usconsumption)`, you'll see that this data set has classes `mts` and `ts`. If you run `str(usconsumption)`, you'll see that it's a `Time Series`. If you read your csv file using `read.csv`, then your data frame is probably of `data frame` class. You'll need to convert it to the appropriate time series class for the modeling function(s) you want to use.

Comment: I'm not sure what the appropriate function is to convert your data to the correct format, but I'd bet that's discussed earlier in Hyndman's text. Probably, you'll need to use the `ts` function or perhaps `xts` (from the `xts` package) or `zoo` (from the `zoo` package).

Comment: Thanks again @eipi10! More questions though. I used the `xts` package with this code. `xts(US_Data_Test$HomRate, as.Date(US_Data_Test$Year, format='%Y')`. Two questions from here.

**1**. How do I do it with multiple non-time variables? I tried separating them with + but got `non-numeric argument to binary operator`. Comma got me `order.by requires an appropriate time-based object`.

**2**. I got this done with just one variable and time, but the output gave me the dates `1975-09-30`, to `1975-10-12`, far from what I want. I suspect saying the format is `'%Y'` is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently learning R too with my main focus being time-series analysis and I'm encountering lots of package conflicts with dates and ggplot2.

As at Nov-2017, it appears the lowest risk approach is described in the [R Times Series Tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/300439_029f7ba592794d1cb2dac8f09d139f51.html) by Matthew Small.

The basic steps are:

1. Import your data
2. Load it into a `xts` object to view and filter it
3. Convert the `xts` object into a standard R `ts` object
4. This `ts` object is more suited for Rob Hyndman's R packages and for use in ggplot2

Please give feedback if there is a better way, lower risk way for people new to R.